# A question about a polynomial sequence and converging.

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, convergence-divergence

We have a continuous function without zeros (roots)

$
f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}
$

Is there any sequence of polynomials $ (p_n) $ so that not one of them has zeros (roots) on $ [0,1] $ and that the sequence uniformly converges to $f$?

Comment: "Evenly" converges? Did you mean "uniformly" converges?

Comment: Yes uniformly converges. Sorry, english isn't my first language

Answer (score 2):

Let $(q_n)$ be a polynomial which converges uniformly to $f$ and let $2 \epsilon = \min_{x \in [0,1]} f(x)$ (where we are assuming $f>0$, WLOG). There is $N$ such that for $n\ge N$, $|q_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x$. Hence $|q_n(x)| > f(x) - \epsilon \ge \epsilon > 0$ for all $x$. Hence for all $n\ge N$, $q_n$ has no roots. Now let $(p_n)$ be the sequence $p_n = q_n$ for $n \ge N$ and $p_n = 1$ otherwise. Then $(p_n)$ is such a polynomial.